# select option box is 1px too high in Chrome when there are 7 or more options

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Try this in Chrome (in Firefox it works without problems):

```html
opened box is perfect size with 6 or fewer options
<br>
<select>
    <option style="background-color:red">red</option>
    <option style="background-color:green">green</option>
    <option style="background-color:blue">blue</option>
    <option style="background-color:cyan">cyan</option>
    <option style="background-color:yellow">yellow</option>
    <option style="background-color:magenta">magenta</option>
</select>
<br>
opened box is 1px too high with 7 or more options
<br>
<select>
    <option style="background-color:red">red</option>
    <option style="background-color:green">green</option>
    <option style="background-color:blue">blue</option>
    <option style="background-color:cyan">cyan</option>
    <option style="background-color:yellow">yellow</option>
    <option style="background-color:magenta">magenta</option>
    <option style="background-color:gray">gray</option>
    <!-- here is 1px white when opened -->
</select>
```

You will notice a white line of 1px at the bottem when you open the select box.

Can this be fixed?

EDIT: Chrome Version 65.0.3325.146

EDIT 2: it appears to depend on screen resolution (tested on 1920x1080 and 1920x1200)

Comment: Damn this is so weird. With 6 and 8 options it's perfect, it only glitches with 7.

Comment: Unfortunately, when it comes to rendering `<select>` elements, browser liberty is quite high and it's done from a level that's not controllable from *Document*. The reasons are various and irrelevant, but this is the current state of things. If you want complete control over how `<select>`s are rendered, you need to mock their behavior using other more controllable elements from a rendering point of view, such as `<div>`s, `<span>`s or `<ul>`s. Or use a library that does the heavy-lifting for you, displaying easily style-able elements.

Comment: @Phiter it also glitches with 9 or 12, ...

Comment: It has to do with sub-pixel-rendering. For me, latest Chrome on Ubuntu 17, setting `font-size` to `14px` fixes it for both 6 and 7 elements, but not sure if it doesn't break on different child elements number. I'd say the safest way to fix it is disregard `font-size` altogether and set `<select>`s `background-color` to the color of the last option. If that's variable, do it via javascript, based on current children number.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu i tried your advice in jsfiddle - it fixes the white line - but then i remembered that in production i set background color to the currently selected option, so this doesn't work

Comment: @JinJi Perhaps you should read my first comment more carefully. You are expecting browsers to render `<select>` and `<option>` the same way and that's just not happening and chances are it will not happen for a very long time, if ever. Besides, it's done at a level you do not control.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu i meant no disrespect, i read your first comment carefully and i understand it. i merely commented that your second suggestion works in some cases, but not in mine. thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this has something to do with screen scaling. I'm using a 2560x1440 resolution screen and can see the issue on any number of options set in the Selection Box. When I drag it down to my 2736 x 1824 screen, I never see that line of white at the bottom.

The latter one is a Surface Pro 4 which renders all pixels in Win 10 native resolution rendering all pixels "as it's meant to be rendered".

I'm suspecting that there might be a gap in certain cases on different screen resolutions for this particular issue.

Looking onto the comments, Andrei's solution seems like the best work-around for what you are trying to accomplish if the solution you're making isn't demanding `<select>` and nothing but a `<select>`.

> Unfortunately, when it comes to rendering `<select>` elements, browser liberty is quite high and it's done from a level that's not controllable from *Document*. The reasons are various and irrelevant, but this is the current state of things. If you want complete control over how `<select>`s are rendered, you need to mock their behavior using other more controllable elements from a rendering point of view, such as `<div>`s, `<span>`s or `<ul>`s. Or use a library that does the heavy-lifting for you, displaying easily style-able elements.

This is from my external monitor with the white line at the bottom

[image: External 1440p monitar render]

When using it on my higher resolution Surface Pro 4, the exact same window (Chrome) looks like this without the white line in the end.

[image: Surface Pro 4 render]

I would say, that a pixel-fix solution on one screen, might cause issues on another depending on the screen resolution.